# converting an function statement to an arrow function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am struggling with understanding the following.

I have the following code:

```
const myFunction = function (error) {
  console.error(error)
  callSomething();
}
```

As you see I am using a function called `callSomething()` and it works but as soon as I use arrow function then `callSomething()` :

```
const myFunction = error => console.error(error);callSomething();
```

Then `callSomething()` is not called.

Comment: How/where do you define `ElasticSearchCallError`?

Comment: Please post your exact code, not some pseudo "do sth".

Comment: Why do you want to use arrow functions if they don't work? [They are different](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/1048572), and there are cases where only either of them fits.

Comment: Remove the `;` in your arrow expression (Here: `(error);`). A proper editor would've thrown an syntax error on there.

Comment: This sample should first and foremost throw syntax errors. Please show something that at least *could* work, and then give us the exact error message you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### From the docs

Omitting the curly braces implies using an expression as the [MDN documentations says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

> **Basic Syntax**

```
(param1, param2, …, paramN) => { statements } (param1, param2, …,
paramN) => expression // equivalent to: (param1, param2, …, paramN) =>
{ return expression; }

// Parentheses are optional when there's only one parameter name:
(singleParam) => { statements } singleParam => { statements }
singleParam => expression

// The parameter list for a function with no parameters should be
written with a pair of parentheses. () => { statements }
```

[Expressions versus statements in Javascript](http://2ality.com/2012/09/expressions-vs-statements.html)

### Explanations

So basically the following should work as `callSomething()` is an expression

```
const myFunction = error => callSomething(error)
```

With statements not being expressions (such as multiple expressions for exemple) the curly braces are mandatory

**Example 1**

```
const myFunction = error => {
  // other statements such as
  console.error(error);
  callSomehting(error);
});
```

**Example 2**

`throw error` is a statement but not an expression!

```
const myFunction = error => {
  throw error;
});
```

Comment: Not that "an expression" would necessarily fail here…

Comment: This doesn't explain why the OP's code doesn't work. not does this explain what the significance of "expressions" is.

Comment: My bad, `ElasticSearchCallError(error);` is an expression indeed

Comment: As OP tagged this as accepted answer, I suspect, he used more than a single function call resulting in multiple statements requiring the curly braces...